# In C# , how can I read a connection string stored in my web.config file connection string?

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string

In C# class library, how can I read a connection string stored in my web.config file connection string tag? As in:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="CLessConStringLocal" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=sa;pwd=mypassword;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) collection to access the connection stings that stored in your configuration files.

For example :

```
string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
          .ConnectionStrings["CLessConStringLocal"].ConnectionString;
```

**Note :** Do not forget to reference to System.Configuration assembly.