# How to get Connection String From the Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# , how can I read a connection string stored in my web.config file connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737393/in-c-sharp-how-can-i-read-a-connection-string-stored-in-my-web-config-file-con)

I am using the SqlConnection class to connect to a sql server database. One of the constructors for this class required a connection string argument...What is the easiest way to get the required information from the web.config file....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) collection to read connection string from web.config.

Answer (score 11):

**connection string in web config**

> 

**import this**

> using System.Configuration;

**in aspx page**

> SqlConnection con;
>
> ```
> string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection string name in web config"].ConnectionString;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First include this Namespace `using System.Configuration;`

and use this

```
string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
```