# Get connection string from an external web.config

Tags: c#, web-config

I have a C# .net 3.5 console app that needs to programatically open up 50 website folders (on the same server) open their root web.config and get the dbname, user, password.

I know how to do this on a single site opening it's own local web.config
[How to get Connection String From the Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412361/how-to-get-connection-string-from-the-web-config)

But how can a console app load external ones?

Would it be like this:

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(site-root-path + "/Web.Config");
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
configuration.ConnectionStrings["storeConn"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Have you tried the code in your own proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

A web config file is just an XML file so you can use any XML parser such as [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and then navigate to the ConnectionStrings node.

Comment: right, but .net has some magic that let's you get parts like ConnectionString.Password